# How to validate response in rest-assured from JSON array content which doesn't have any array name?

Tags: arrays, json, web-services, rest, rest-assured

I am finding hard.
How to validate below content from the response using Rest-Assured?

```
       {  
            "code":268,
            "name":"Result-Code",
            "value":2001,
            "type":"UNSIGNED32",
            "group":[  

            ],
            "grouped":false
        },
```

If this is my response:

```
[  
{  
    "avps":[  
        {  
            "code":263,
            "name":"Session-Id",
            "value":"ocstest;766666665;766666665",
            "type":"UTF8STRING",
            "group":[  

            ],
            "grouped":false
        },
        {  
            "code":260,
            "name":"Vendor-Specific-Application-Id",
            "value":"<Grouped>",
            "type":"GROUPED",
            "group":[  
                {  
                    "code":265,
                    "name":"Supported-Vendor-Id",
                    "value":0,
                    "type":"UNSIGNED32",
                    "group":[  

                    ],
                    "grouped":false
                },
                {  
                    "code":258,
                    "name":"Auth-Application-Id",
                    "value":4,
                    "type":"UNSIGNED32",
                    "group":[  

                    ],
                    "grouped":false
                },
                {  
                    "code":259,
                    "name":"Acct-Application-Id",
                    "value":0,
                    "type":"UNSIGNED32",
                    "group":[  

                    ],
                    "grouped":false
                }
            ],
            "grouped":true
        },
        {  
            "code":268,
            "name":"Result-Code",
            "value":2001,
            "type":"UNSIGNED32",
            "group":[  

            ],
            "grouped":false
        },
        {  
            "code":416,
            "name":"CC-Request-Type",
            "value":1,
            "type":"INT32",
            "group":[  

            ],
            "grouped":false
        },
        {  
            "code":415,
            "name":"CC-Request-Number",
            "value":0,
            "type":"UNSIGNED32",
            "group":[  

            ],
            "grouped":false
        },
        {  
            "code":431,
            "name":"Granted-Service-Unit",
            "value":"<Grouped>",
            "type":"GROUPED",
            "group":[  
                {  
                    "code":420,
                    "name":"CC-Time",
                    "value":240,
                    "type":"UNSIGNED32",
                    "group":[  

                    ],
                    "grouped":false
                }
            ],
            "grouped":true
        }
    ]
},
{  
    "avps":[  
        {  
            "code":263,
            "name":"Session-Id",
            "value":"ocstest;766666665;766666665",
            "type":"UTF8STRING",
            "group":[  

            ],
            "grouped":false
        },
        {  
            "code":260,
            "name":"Vendor-Specific-Application-Id",
            "value":"<Grouped>",
            "type":"GROUPED",
            "group":[  
                {  
                    "code":265,
                    "name":"Supported-Vendor-Id",
                    "value":0,
                    "type":"UNSIGNED32",
                    "group":[  

                    ],
                    "grouped":false
                },
                {  
                    "code":258,
                    "name":"Auth-Application-Id",
                    "value":4,
                    "type":"UNSIGNED32",
                    "group":[  

                    ],
                    "grouped":false
                },
                {  
                    "code":259,
                    "name":"Acct-Application-Id",
                    "value":0,
                    "type":"UNSIGNED32",
                    "group":[  

                    ],
                    "grouped":false
                }
            ],
            "grouped":true
        },
        {  
            "code":268,
            "name":"Result-Code",
            "value":5004,
            "type":"UNSIGNED32",
            "group":[  

            ],
            "grouped":false
        },
        {  
            "code":416,
            "name":"CC-Request-Type",
            "value":2,
            "type":"INT32",
            "group":[  

            ],
            "grouped":false
        },
        {  
            "code":415,
            "name":"CC-Request-Number",
            "value":1,
            "type":"UNSIGNED32",
            "group":[  

            ],
            "grouped":false
        }
    ]
},
{  
    "avps":[  
        {  
            "code":263,
            "name":"Session-Id",
            "value":"ocstest;766666666;788888888",
            "type":"UTF8STRING",
            "group":[  

            ],
            "grouped":false
        },
        {  
            "code":260,
            "name":"Vendor-Specific-Application-Id",
            "value":"<Grouped>",
            "type":"GROUPED",
            "group":[  
                {  
                    "code":265,
                    "name":"Supported-Vendor-Id",
                    "value":0,
                    "type":"UNSIGNED32",
                    "group":[  

                    ],
                    "grouped":false
                },
                {  
                    "code":258,
                    "name":"Auth-Application-Id",
                    "value":4,
                    "type":"UNSIGNED32",
                    "group":[  

                    ],
                    "grouped":false
                },
                {  
                    "code":259,
                    "name":"Acct-Application-Id",
                    "value":0,
                    "type":"UNSIGNED32",
                    "group":[  

                    ],
                    "grouped":false
                }
            ],
            "grouped":true
        },
        {  
            "code":268,
            "name":"Result-Code",
            "value":5002,
            "type":"UNSIGNED32",
            "group":[  

            ],
            "grouped":false
        },
        {  
            "code":416,
            "name":"CC-Request-Type",
            "value":3,
            "type":"INT32",
            "group":[  

            ],
            "grouped":false
        },
        {  
            "code":415,
            "name":"CC-Request-Number",
            "value":2,
            "type":"UNSIGNED32",
            "group":[  

            ],
            "grouped":false
        }
    ]
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the most efficient way to do - but I was able to validate 'Result-Code' with below method..

`avps.findAll { 'Result-Code' in it.name }.value[0][2]", is(2001)`

Thanks

Comment: Above, if sequence of array element changes then it will not work. Please suggest more robust method.